# I am using Microsoft's Face API. It requires to create a DB at their server. is it possible to use our own DB, rather than creating one at their end

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am trying to use Microsoft's Face API, for facial recognition for my company employees. I see that you need to create a database in Microsoft's serverS.

1. Is there a way to use their API's on our company database (without creating another DB on their server? Also any changes you make to this DB will be taken care of.
2. If no, then how will you take care of the changes you want (I know that there are delete API calls as well, but will not it be cumbersome?)

Comment: No, they don't offer a self-hosted solution.

Comment: Ohkay. Thanks Maria. Can someone help me with this please ?

Comment: There is nothing to do here, you have to use their servers

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have misunderstood how this API works.  Whenever there is a change to your list of employees, the `PersonGroup` (a friendly name for the image classifier model), must be [retrained](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395249) in order for it to start recognizing the added faces and stop recognizing removed ones.  So even if there was a way to store the model locally (which there isn't), you will still need to track add/removes and take the additional step of training.